# Can I script an "in-shell" editor for commit messages?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I wanted to write a bash alias for the `git commit` command. I typically use it like so: `git commit -m "my message here"`, so I wrote an alias like this:

```
alias commit='git commit'
```

which allows me to do this:

```
$ commit -m "My message"
```

However, then I thought I could also update my alias to remove the `-m` option, getting me

```
$ commit "my message"
```

*Then* I thought, "Do I even need to type the quotes?" What I envisioned was this:

```
$ commit
> My message here
```

Where `>` is the quote-continuation prompt you get when you are type enter in a quoted string:

```
$ git commit -m "I am about to hit the enter key
>
```

And it completes the command when I hit enter.

Is there any way I can script this behavior in bash?

Bonus: the command aborts when I hit `Ctrl`+`c`.

Comment: It appears you want to re-implement `git commit` *without* the `-m` option.

Comment: @glennjackman A fair assessment-- but with the caveat that I still want its feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you want this function:

```
commit() {
    if (( $# == 0 )); then
        command git commit  # no `-m`: invoke an editor
    else
        command git commit -m "$*"
    fi
}
```

As you don't want to open an editor, perhaps:

```
commit() {
    [[ $# -eq 0 ]] && set -- A default commit message here.
    command git commit -m "$*"
}
```

Comment: My git doesn't behave this way `$ git commit
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ git version
git version 2.7.4`

Comment: You have to do something commit worthy first: `touch some_file; git add some_file; git commit`

Comment: Ah, okay, I see, thanks. I don't want to open an editor; I just want to avoid typing quote marks.

Comment: expanded my answer.

Comment: So now I have the command where I can write `commit this is my commit message`. But I wonder, can I get it so that I type `commit`, hit enter, and get a prompt like this: `>`, where I type my commit message, and cancel with `Ctrl`+`c`?

Answer (score 4):

You could write a function that uses `bash`'s `read -e`:

```bsh
commit() {
  local commitlog
  IFS= read -rep '> ' commitlog &&
     git commit -m "$commitlog" "$@"
}
```

`read -e` lets you insert a litterral newline by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd>, but because `read` reads only one line, everything past the first newline will be discarded.

You can work around that by adding a `-d $'\r'` option to `read`, but then [I found that at least with version 5.0.7 and 4.4.19, that messes up the handling of <kbd>Enter</kbd> afterwards at the prompt](https://www.mail-archive.com/bug-bash@gnu.org/msg23081.html).

In any case, it's easier in `zsh`:

```bsh
commit() {
  local commitlog=
  vared -ep '> ' commitlog &&
    git commit -m "$commitlog" "$@"
}
```

Where newline can be entered with <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd> like in `bash` or with <kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd>

Or with history (here shared and avoiding duplicates):

```bsh
commit() {
  emulate -L zsh
  setopt sharehistory histignorealldups histsavenodups
  local commitlog=
  fc -ap ~/.zcommit-history 500
  vared -ehp '> ' commitlog || return
  print -rs -- "$commitlog"
  git commit -m "$commitlog" "$@"
}
```